# Protractor Promises

Tags: promise, protractor

I am just a week old with protractor and Jasmine. I am trying a hand at Promises. My test is trying to get the original text of the element and rename it with a new text. Below is the code I am trying, but the output isn't as expected:

```
    element(by.css("css of the element")).getText().then(function(oldText) {
    newElementName= oldText + "-New Name";
});

    browser.actions().doubleClick(element(by.css("css of the element")).perform();
    element(by.css("")).sendKeys(newElementName,protractor.Key.ENTER);

    element(by.css("")).getText().
          then(function(afterRename) {
            expect(afterRename).toEqual(newElementName);
```

I wanted the value of "newElementName" to be "oldText-New Name" but instead it is set to "undefined".

As per my understanding so far, the scripts are parsed and a chain of promises are created, referenced from https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/909. So for the above code the promises would be in the order .getText(), .then(), .perform() [referenced](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angular-protractor--angular-protractor/classes/webdriver.actionsequence.html), .sendKeys(), .getText(), .then(), expect().

Why .perform() and .sendkeys() get performed before newElementName gets resolved?
Note: the text cannot be edited without double-clicking the element.

Also does anyone have any good tutorial or link for "deferred objects"? I looked at many links but couldn't find anything good to help me with the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `getText()` promise will not have resolved when you call `sendKeys()`. It will resolve before the promise returned by `sendKeys()` resolves, but at that point it's too late: the argument (`newElementName`) has already been passed with an undefined value.

What you will need to do is have the first promise resolve before even calling `sendKeys()`. Also, keep in mind that an [ElementFinder](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) can be reused.

```
var theElement = element(by.css("css of the element"));
theElement.getText().then(function(oldText) {
  newElementName = oldText + "-New Name";
  browser.actions()
    .doubleClick(theElement)
    .sendKeys(newElementName, protractor.Key.ENTER)
    .perform();
  afterRename = theElement.getText();
});

expect(afterRename).toEqual(newElementName);
```

Comment: Thanks SkinnyJ! thats exactly how my current code looks like. but I thought the "controlFlow" will move to the next promise(sendKeys()) once earlier (then()) is resolved.

Comment: pressed enter too fast, here is the full comment:

But if you consider old code, I thought the "controlFlow" will move to the next promise(sendKeys()) once earlier promise (getText()) is resolved. Just want to understand Promises and their async nature, let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @FindABug the control flow ensure that the promises ***resolve*** in order, but the actual functions are all called immediately, before any promises resolve. [Here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) is a decent description.

Comment: Edited the answer slightly to ensure that the "after rename" `getText()` resolves after the actual rename.

Comment: @FindABug I noticed that you accepted and then un-accepted this answer. Does it work?

Comment: Some sneaky mouse click that happened, sorry about that. It does work.

Comment: Ok, could you elaborate a little on " the actual functions are all called immediately, before any promises resolve" ? If I understand correctly, getText, then, .perform, .sendkeys, getText, and then is the order the promises will be resolved. but the actions like, doubleclick, perform(even though returns a promise), assignment(=) operation are executed before promise are actually resolved. [link](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/) section ControlFlow we can see sendKeys() happen after get() (just an e.g.)

Comment: Did you see the example in the link from my earlier comment?

Comment: yep I did went through the links. Is there something I should know before reading through those docs?

Comment: @FindABug besides promise natures, the code is still regular JavaScript and there is no magic with that: at line `5` in your code the variable `newElementName` indeed has no value. Basically all the code is read synchronously and every method is added to a buffer that will execute them one by one, resolving the promises in their given order. So the callback passed to `getText().then` will indeed be called before the callback passed to `sendKeys().then`.